# array as rvalue on single line which works with C++2003?

Tags: c++, iso

I am parsing some text and it would make my life easier if i can use arrays are rvalues rather then defining it on their own line. I have done this

```
 int a[]={1,2,3}; //its own line. Do not want
```

and

```
 func([]()->int*{static int a[]={1,2,3}; return a; }()); //It compiles but untested. It doesn't compile with 2003
```

i tried

```
 func(int []={1,2,3}); //but got a compile error bc this is simply illegal
```

I can put additional things at the end of the line but not before. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with C++0x, but still, the lambda seems to create undefined behaviour, because it returns a pointer to a local array filled with {1,2,3}.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @stefaanv: I think your right. I didnt test it thoroughly. I just know i cant use it as a solution as i need 2003 support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func([]()->int*{int a[]={1,2,3}; return a; }()); //works well on C++0x.
```

I find interesting the comment *works well*. I am not a lambda lawyer, but I believe that the code above is returning a pointer into a local variable, and that is undefined behavior, so even if that compiles that does not mean that it is correct.

As to what happens under the hood, my understanding is that the compiler transforms the lambda into a functor in a way similar to (note that this is a simplification taking into consideration that there are no captures, and the exact lambda:

```
struct __lambda {
   // no captures: no constructor needed, no member objects needed
   int* operator()() {        // returns int*, no arguments

      int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };  // auto variable
      return a;               // return &a[0], address of a local object
   }
};
```

Comment: nice catch. I actually threw the `static` keyword in there and didnt  test it out or edit the question. I guess i need a new way to parse this. I am thinking multiple streams (line, preline, postline)

Comment: If you add a `static`, then you are changing the storage qualifier and the code will be correct, *but* you will be keeping that object in memory for the whole duration of the program. Which means that if the `1, 2, 3` is a simplification and you want to create them based on captured objects, things will become messier. You can look at the implementation of boost assign for some ideas on what can be done with C++03 to this respect.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but you can do the following:

```
  for ( int a[3] = {1, 2, 3}; func( a ), false; );
```

Note, that Microsoft compiler doesn't support it, but it is valid according to C++'03 Standard.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do in C++03 is encase the array in a struct/class. Then the whole object can be passed.

Comment: can i get an example? I took a guess and was way wrong (i know you can define structs in a func body tho) `(struct { int a[]={1,2,3}; int*get(){return a; } } a).get();`

Comment: oh and pass the struct instead of array. well. i really do need the array and cant change the function prototype. But thats at least an idea.

Comment: Yes, you got my gist. I'm still learning this (Stack Overflow) interface. I was going to post more code, but everytime I hit [return], the comment closes out.

Comment: haha, yeah. tips are shift+enter is a new line. http://www.ideone.com/ and http://codepad.org/ are used to show working examples and http://www.pastie.org/ is a fine paste site for non runable examples. You can also @three_or_more_letters to alert someone but if its their answer you dont need to do it